# IEnumerable will not shuffle unless I put a breakpoint

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, asynchronous

I am trying to shuffle the elements in a list using the fisher-yates shuffle. However, it appears that the elements will not shuffle unless I put a breakpoint at the point in which it is supposed to shuffle. I tried executing the shuffle asynchronously but I had no luck (maybe I did it wrong).

The shuffle algorithm is as follows:

```
// Uses Fisher-Yates shuffle to swap elements
    public static IEnumerable<T> Shuffle<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        Random rng = new Random();
        T[] elements = source.ToArray();

        for (int i = elements.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            int j = rng.Next(i + 1);
            yield return elements[j];
            elements[j] = elements[i];
        }

    }
```

I shuffle like this:

```
imageDataList= imageDataList.Shuffle().ToList();
```

I shuffled asynchronously like this:

```
imageDataList = await Task.Run(() => imageDataList.Shuffle().ToList());
```

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
GameData gameData = null;
ImageData imageData = null;
ToneData toneData = null;
ImageToneData imageToneData = null;
LevelData levelData = null;

List<ImageData> imageDataList = new List<ImageData>();
List<ToneData> toneDataList = new List<ToneData>();
List<ImageToneData> imageToneDataList = new List<ImageToneData>();
List<LevelData> levelDataList = new List<LevelData>();

 // Add images to a list of ImageData contracts
    foreach (GameImage gameImage in game.GameImages)
    {
        imageData = new ImageData()
        {
            ImageId = gameImage.Image.ImageId,
            ImageFileName = gameImage.Image.ImageFileName
        };

        imageDataList.Add(imageData);

    }

    // Add tones to a list of ToneData contracts
    foreach (GameTone gameTone in game.GameTones)
    {
        toneData = new ToneData()
        {
            ToneId = gameTone.Tone.ToneId,
            ToneFileName = gameTone.Tone.ToneFileName
        };

        toneDataList.Add(toneData);
    }


    //Randomize image and tone association
    imageDataList = imageDataList.Shuffle().ToList();
    toneDataList = toneDataList.Shuffle().ToList();

    // Combine imageData and toneData and assign a position
    for (int i = 0; i < game.NumLevels; i++)
    {
        imageToneData = new ImageToneData()
        {
            Image = imageDataList.ElementAt(i),
            Tone = toneDataList.ElementAt(i),
            Position = (i + 1)
        };

        imageToneDataList.Add(imageToneData);

    }

    foreach (GameLevel level in game.GameLevels)
    {
        //Randomize image/tone (already fixed association)
        imageToneDataList = imageToneDataList.Shuffle().ToList();

        levelData = new LevelData()
        {
            GameLevelId = level.GameLevelId,
            Level = level.Level,
            UniqueRounds = level.UniqueRounds,
            Rounds = level.Rounds,
            NumImages = level.NumImages,
            ImageTones = imageToneDataList.Take(level.NumImages)
        };

        levelDataList.Add(levelData);
    }

gameData = new GameData()
{
    NumLevels = game.NumLevels,
    SelectionTime = game.SelectionTime,
    Levels = levelDataList
};
```

My data contracts are as follows:

```
  [DataContract]
    public class GameData
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int NumLevels { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public int? SelectionTime { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public IEnumerable<LevelData> Levels { get; set; }
    }

[DataContract]
public class LevelData
{
    [DataMember]
    public int GameLevelId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int Level { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public bool UniqueRounds { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int Rounds { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int NumImages { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public IEnumerable<ImageToneData> ImageTones { get; set; }

}


[DataContract]
public class ImageToneData
{
    [DataMember]
    public ImageData Image { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public ToneData Tone { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int? Position { get; set; }

}


[DataContract]
public class ImageData
{
    [DataMember]
    public int ImageId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string ImageFileName { get; set; }
}


[DataContract]
public class ToneData
{

    [DataMember]
    public int ToneId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string ToneFileName { get; set; }
}
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Place the code in an empty console project. Is the problem still there? It won't be.

Comment: Try making `elements` a list, and remove them each time you yield one.

Comment: @usr I have the code in a separate class in a separate project

Comment: The bug is in code not shown here. Putting this code in a fresh project proves that. Find out what code causes the bug. In particular post the calling code.

Comment: @PhilippeParé That's *dramatically* less performant. You're turning an O(n) shuffle into an O(n^2) shuffle by doing that.

Comment: I had two shuffles happening simultaneously `imageDataList = imageDataList.Shuffle().ToList();` `toneDataList = toneDataList.Shuffle().ToList();`. When I comment out one of them the issue seems to be resolved. Do you know why this is?

Comment: @EitanK You'll need to provide a complete reproducible example.  Provide us with a program that we can run, explain what the expected output is, what the actual output is, and how they differ.

Comment: @Servy I have a O(n) algorithm that fits in this model, using what I suggested

Comment: @Servy I added more code I hope it helps. I feel like adding any more will be too much

Comment: @PhilippeParé That's an O(n^2) algorithm.

Comment: How are you determining that one of them was not shuffled?  Are comparing the results of `imageDataList` and `toneDataList` pre and post shuffle or are you looking at the `imageToneDataList`?

Comment: @JasonBoyd I created a test page which shows the images and their associated tones. When i refresh the page, the image/tone association is always the same. When I comment out the shuffle on toneDataList the image/tone association becomes different. When shuffling both the imageDataList and toneDataList, it only shuffles when I put a breakpoint at that point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that the two lists, `imageDataList` and `toneDataList`, are actually being shuffled.  I suspect that they have the appearance of not being shuffled because each time you run that code, when you combine the two lists into `imageToneDataList`, the same tone keeps getting paired with the same image as the last time you ran the code.  This is because your `Shuffle` method is instantiating a new `Random` each time it is called.  `Random` uses the systems clock to generate its seed.  So if you instantiate two `Random` objects back to back (like you are doing by calling `Shuffle` twice in a row) there is a very high probability that they will have the same seed.  That means they will generate the same random numbers.  Which means your two lists are being shuffled in the exact same order.  This explains why it appears to work correctly when you only shuffle one list.  when you combine the shuffled list with the list that was not shuffled into `imageToneDataList` you get the random result that you expect.  This also explains why it works when you use a break point.  They delay between the first time you call `Shuffle` and the second is long enough to create a `Random` object with a new seed.

To get the behavior you are expecting you need to have a single instance of `Random` - perhaps a static field in the class containing your extension method.

Answer (score -1):

I would change the method to something like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Shuffle<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    Random rng = new Random();
    List<T> elements = source.ToList();

    while (elements.Count > 0)
    {
        int i = rng.Next(elements.Count);
        T item = elements[i];
        elements.RemoveAt(i);
        yield return item;
    }
}
```

Comment: The is just a strictly worse version of the OP's solution.

Comment: Can you define why is that? I'm just curious

Comment: I already have above.  I does exactly the same thing, just slower, and wouldn't fix whatever problem the OP has with his program.  As several people have already said, the OP's implementation of this method is perfectly fine.

Comment: @Servy is correct that the runtime of this solution is O(n^2).  The reason is because `RemoveAt` has runtime of O(n) for `List<T>`.  Combine that with the while loop and you get a runtime of O(n^2).

Comment: Just checked on referencesource.microsoft.com, List<T>.RemoveAt(int) is O(1). List<T>.Remove(T) in the other end is O(n).

Comment: @PhilippeParé No, `RemoveAt` is *not* O(1).  It needs to move every single item after the remove item up one in the list, which is an O(n) operation.

Comment: It actually uses Array.Copy to move the objects